# remove title subplots in pandas.plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

I generate a subplot figure using the following code.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,1,2],[2,1,2],[3,1,2]],columns=['day','var1','var2'])
df.plot(x='day',y=['var1','var2'],
         kind='bar',subplots=True,sharex=True,title=None,legend=None)
```

How can I remove the title to the subplots?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: I added an example

Comment: @gabboshow - In my opinion you have nice questions. But only one friend notice - please add some code, what you try. Because I think this is reason for downvotes. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `title` keyword when used in conjunction with `subplots=True` takes a list of titles to use for each subplot, as can be seen in [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html). Hence, if you use an empty string for each:

```
df.plot(x='day',y=['var1','var2'],
        kind='bar',subplots=True,sharex=True,title=['', ''],legend=None)
```

You get the desired title-less output:
[image]

Comment: Just to piggyback on this: you can also use [suptitle](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.suptitle.html) to add a title to your figure once you have removed the subplot titles.